# How to return the next date in the table where it matches the SKU (field) within that row?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of records showing each date a change was made to a product (SKU) cost price.

I need to populate the table so that it finds the next date where this SKU was costed and return that date into the column (effectively creating a to and from date type field).

example table:

| SKU | Cost | Date_Costed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **R001** | **£4.50** | **01/03/2023** |
| R002 | £3.82 | 01/03/2023 |
| **R001** | **£4.54** | **13/03/2023** |
| R004 | £1.92 | 13/03/2023 |
| **R001** | **£4.69** | **31/03/2023** |

I'd expect this result from a query where i want to add this column to that dataset but i'm struggling to get it to find just the next iteration and instead all my results so far are returning the max last date:

| SKU | Cost | Date_Costed | Date_Next_Costed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **R001** | **£4.50** | **01/03/2023** | **13/03/2023** |
| R002 | £3.82 | 01/03/2023 | 01/03/2023 |
| **R001** | **£4.54** | **13/03/2023** | **31/03/2023** |
| R004 | £1.92 | 13/03/2023 | 01/03/2023 |
| **R001** | **£4.69** | **31/03/2023** |  |

My apologies if the question header doesn't make lots of sense. i'm not sure on how best to phrase what i'm looking to do but can demonstrate the expected result.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for this. But notice that R002 and R003 don't have a Date_Next_Costed because there isn't one. Not sure why in your sample output you have that for those two SKUs but not the last one for R001.

```
set dateformat dmy --because your date strings can be ambiguous

create table #something
(
    SKU varchar(5)
    , Cost varchar(10)
    , Date_Costed date
)
insert #something values
('R001', '£4.50', '01/03/2023')
, ('R002', '£3.82', '01/03/2023')
, ('R001', '£4.54', '13/03/2023')
, ('R004', '£1.92', '13/03/2023')
, ('R001', '£4.69', '31/03/2023')

select SKU
    , Cost
    , Date_Costed
    , Date_Next_Costed = lead(Date_Costed, 1) over(partition by SKU order by Date_Costed)
from #something
order by SKU
    , Date_Costed

drop table #something
```